# How do I show a slider inline with forms using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a website where I want to show an app sample screen inline with a form I have made.

I've tried added the following code to the slider's CSS:

`display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: no-wrap;`

but to no avail.

The site is made using Bootstrap 4.0. You can view it here: https://pao.sg/gowhere/index

Here's a screenshot of what I want to achieve:

[image]

All help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: please create two div
in 1st div add class (col-md-7) show your form
and in 2nd div add class (col-md--5) show your image

Comment: Your question is not clear... it would be ideal if you could include a [Minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @HoomanBahreini, The app slider (the thing circled in red) is the thing I wish to move to the right of the form.

Comment: @SharmaVikram, not entirely sure what you mean.

Comment: I would say that menu is messing with the grid but you would need to include some html for us to provide help

Comment: Here is the link you can check it
https://ibb.co/94Hst8D
Please check html code in inspect element of image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove col-md-7 from class containing header-text and add col-xs-6 to 2 divs inside (form and image)

```html
<div class="row v-center">
                <div class="col-xs-12 header-text">
                    <h2>Travel Deals Over Messaging</h2>
                    <p>Best Travel Deals over Facebook Messenger or WhatsApp.</p>
                    <!-- Search form -->
                  <div class="form-row **col-xs-6**">
                    ....
                </div>
                <div class="hidden-xs **col-xs-6** hidden-sm">
                   .....
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Tried this, doesn't work, or maybe I'm doing something wrong? This is my output:

https://i.imgur.com/RMUQzmb.jpg

Comment: it is working for me, i have updated the ans ..check if you are updating the right div

Answer (score 2):

add 'col-md-6' to form div and the div with images and change `col-md-7` to `col-md-12`. below is the output screen shot[image]

replace this code with yours

```
div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 header-text">
                <h2>Travel Deals Over Messaging</h2>
                <p>Best Travel Deals over Facebook Messenger or WhatsApp.</p>
                <!-- Search form -->
              <div class="form-row col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="travelFrom">Travelling from:</label>
                  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Singapore" readonly="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="travelTo">Travelling to:</label>
                  <select class="form-control" id="to">
                    <option>Indonesia</option>
                    <option>Malaysia</option>
                    <option>Thailand</option>
                    <option>Hong Kong</option>
                    <option>South Korea</option>
                    <option>Japan</option>
                    <option>Maldives</option>
                    <option>Others</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                  <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Number of Travellers:</label>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the number of travellers">
                <a href="https://m.me/weekendgowheresg" class="fb-msg-btn" target="_blank"><img src="https://cdn.snaptravel.com/facebook-messenger-white.svg" style="width:30px;height:30px" alt="Facebook Messenger logo">Get Deal on Messenger</a>
                <a href="https://wa.me/93900052" class="wa-msg-btn" target="_blank"><img src="images/whatsapp.svg" style="width:30px;height:30px" alt="WhatsApp logo">Get Deal on WhatsApp</a>
            </div>
            <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-8 text-right">
                <div class="screen-box screen-slider owl-carousel owl-theme owl-responsive--1 owl-center owl-loaded">





                <div class="owl-stage-outer"><div class="owl-stage" style="transition: all 0s ease 0s; width: 2178px; transform: translate3d(-726px, 0px, 0px);"><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 242px; margin-right: 0px;"><div class="item">
                        <img src="images/screen-4.jpg" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 242px; margin-right: 0px;"><div class="item">
                        <img src="images/screen-5.jpg" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item animated owl-animated-out fadeOut" style="width: 242px; margin-right: 0px; left: 242px;"><div class="item">
                        <img src="images/pixel_very_silver_portrait.png" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item animated owl-animated-in fadeIn active center" style="width: 242px; margin-right: 0px;"><div class="item">
                        <img src="images/screen-2.jpg" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 242px; margin-right: 0px;"><div class="item">
                        <img src="images/screen-3.jpg" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 242px; margin-right: 0px;"><div class="item">
                        <img src="images/screen-4.jpg" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 242px; margin-right: 0px;"><div class="item">
                        <img src="images/screen-5.jpg" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 242px; margin-right: 0px;"><div class="item">
                        <img src="images/pixel_very_silver_portrait.png" alt="">
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 242px; margin-right: 0px;"><div class="item">
                        <img src="images/screen-2.jpg" alt="">
                    </div></div></div></div><div class="owl-controls"><div class="owl-nav"><div class="owl-prev" style=""><i class="ti-arrow-left"></i></div><div class="owl-next" style=""><i class="ti-arrow-right"></i></div></div><div class="owl-dots" style=""><div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div><div class="owl-dot active"><span></span></div><div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div><div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div><div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div></div></div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I want the app slider to still remain as a slider though, not showing all the images.

Comment: give `col-md-4` to form and `col-md-8` to the slider

Comment: Tried it, this is how it looks like now: https://i.imgur.com/76JMrR8.jpg

Comment: but when i do inspect element that time it works.. you must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap you can use their grid,

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-7">
      <!-- Your form -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-5">
      <!-- Slider -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```